# My development database and production database schema has become different somehow and I can't synchronize them. How to handle this situation?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, deployment, rails-migrations

I don't exactly know how it came to be this way, but here's the situation:

```
1. I was experimenting with the combination of "git reset --hard HEAD" and "git clean -f" 
2. For some reason when I did this, it only removed the migration file, but didn't really revert my sqlite database to the previous version.
3. I committed and pushed some more without realizing this
4. At the point I found this out, my development server had the following code:

    create_table "invitations", :force => true do |t|
        t.string "recipient_email"
        t.datetime "created_at"
        t.datetime "updated_at"
    end

   but my production server doesn't.
5. I tried to generate a new migration that drops invitations table. It works on the dev server since there is an existing invitations table. However when I push it and try to rake db:migrate on Heroku, it spits out error (obviously) because there is no such table over there to drop.
```

How can I get around this problem, moving on? Right now, one way I can think of is running a migration on the dev server once, after which I remove the migration file, so there would be no history of this drop_table migration left. But i'm not sure if this is the right way. Could anyone enlighten me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, the easiest (and, arguably, most correct) way is to drop your `invitations` table in the development. You don't even have to create a (temporary) migration file, just drop it from the console or admin tool.